# Subgroup of $G$ maximal with respect to $g\notin U$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group and $g\in G$ not the neutral element. I want to show that there is a maximal subgroup $U$ in $G$ with $g\notin U$.

My idea. I want to use Zorn's Lemma. So i defined $$H=\{U\subseteq G: U \text{ is a subgroup and }g\notin U\}.$$ The set $H$ is partially ordered by $\subseteq$. Let now $K$ be a chain. I define $$K':=\bigcup_{U\in K}U.$$ Then since $K$ is a chain in $H$ we have $g\notin U$ for all $U\in K$, so indeed $g\notin K'$. Clearly $$K'\subseteq G.$$ Besides we have $U\subseteq K$ for all $U\in K$, so $K'$ is an upper bound. But why is $K'$ again a subgroup?

Comment: The claim is not true. Take for example the cyclic group of order $4$ and its unique element of order $2$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Isn't trivial subgroup $\{e\}$ enough in that case?

Comment: Ahh, so you are looking for a subgroup maximal with respect to not containing the element, rather than a maximal subgroup which happens to not contain the element.

Comment: Yes! Thats it. Anf of couse my $H$ is not empty, since $\{e\}\in H$.

Comment: Any union of a chain of subgroups is a subgroup. Just use the definition of a chain in a partial order set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $k_1, k_2 \in K',$ they come from some of the groups $U_1, U_2$ in the chain, i.e. $k_1 \in U_1, \; k_2 \in U_2$. The chain is linearly ordered, so wlog we may assume $U_2 \subseteq U_1$. Then $k_1, k_2 \in U_1$ and thus, $k_1k_2,\; k_1^{-1} \in U_1 \subseteq K'$.